# Bottom line of text, ignoring line height?

Tags: html, css

I have two containers one on top of each other, the top one has a few paragraphs of text in it.

I need the bottom line of text to be 50px above the bottom container.

So i have either 50px margin bottom to the top container, or 50px top margin to the bottom container.

The problem is that its not 50px exactly from the bottom line of text because of the line height applied to the text.

Is there anyway to make text sit flush at the bottom when it reaches that point?

Hope that makes sense... i appreciate its only minor but some clients want it specific.

Comment: html?css?fiddle?anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting `line-height` in the top container the same as its `font-size` and border at the bottom:

```
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
marign-bottom: 50px;
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9KLL/)**

Comment: Thank you i'll try that, seems a bit better. Client want it flush under the text though...

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately as the line height needs to be larger than the font size :(

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or some code? I would need to know what's inside your top div.

Comment: There is no set code, just wondered if it could be done. Your jsfiddle is right, just increase the line height and you’ll see it messes it all up.

Answer (score 0):

try using `padding-bottom` instead of `margin`

Comment: padding and margin results in the same, just used margin in the example.